# Combining $("#myId").val() with $(this).val()

Tags: jquery, this

I would like to combine

```
$("#myId").val()
```

and

```
$(this).val()
```

so that I can use the same id and a name value connected to an array -- `characters[x].name` -- to store and display different names.

http://jsfiddle.net/ren1999/Fae95/

Comment: Could you perhaps post relevant code on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ren1999/Fae95/

Comment: Do you want to store the id's of the input names and the <b> in an array? To reduce the code duplication?

Comment: Dogbert, thanks for your quick replies. I would love to reduce as much code as possible on principle. I assume I could create an array of ids such as nameId[0], nameId[1]. I just don't know the syntax. Here is the D&D Combat Tracker I'm playing with. I want to JQuery-ize it. http://kira3696.tripod.com/CombatTracker.rar

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the layout of input elements is somewhat similar, you could just find the sibling of the input box, and assign the text to it.

```
$("#getName1, #getName2").blur(function() {
    var name = $(this).val();
    $(this).siblings('b').text(name);
}).blur();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fae95/1/

Comment: Thank you for helping me to clarify the problem. The user of the program can add characters so I would need to find a way to keep adding #getName+the next numbers..

Comment: I need something like $("THIS #getName").blur(function() {
    var name = $(this).val();

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.each([["#getName1", "#displayName1"], ["#getName2", "#displayName2"]], 
function (i, names) {
    $(names[0]).blur(function () {
        var name=$(this).val();
        $(names[1]).text(name);
    });
})
```

You can simply add more inputs by adding them too the array.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ren1999/Fae95/4/ Thanks all, I'm trying out your suggestions and they work for certain things I'm trying to do. This latest update in JsFiddle is one of my main goals though. I want to get the value of this.customId and this.name on each character sheet form so that I can the two fields with the same id to store different name values. As it is, only the first id can store and display a value.

Comment: response2=$("#getName", this).val() can I do something like this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ren1999/Fae95/5/ Exelian, here is your code that I modified. Can we keep just one id, and store 2 names?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean. Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish (as in, the final goal).

Comment: Thanks. I want to duplicate forms every time I create a new character and save values such as name race etc.. for each form.

Comment: response2=0
function askName(x)
 {response="<input class=widgetstyle onKeyUp=getName(this.value) size=10 type=text value="+response2+">"
   characters[x].setName(response)
    if(response2!=0)
     {response=response2
      response2=0
       characters[x].setName(response)}
 }
function getName(x)
 {response2=x} This function is what I was trying to do. The problem with it now is keeping the cursor I focused inside the field.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to my problem. I am able to make a field appear, enter a new value, click the field again and make the field disappear with the new value. The Firefox error console complains every time that this.refresh() is not a function, but I don't care as it works.

```
var gotIt='no'

    function askName(x)
     {if(gotIt=='yes')
       {response=this.name
        characters[x].setName(response)
        gotIt=0
       }
      else
       {gotIt='no'
        this.name=characters[x].name
        response="<input onClick=_setName(this.value) size=10 type=text value="+this.name+">"
        characters[x].setName(response)
       }
     }
    function _setName(x)
     {this.name=x
      this.refresh()
      gotIt='yes'
     }
```